# POST golang request with string data

Tags: rest, go

I can do a POST request with string data, using POSTMAN chrome extension.

[image]

I need to do the same using `golang` code.

But my `Go` code loses string `INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19` and posts empty data to the server.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    // Why this stringData is lost and was not send with POST request?
    stringData := `INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19`
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:2480/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql", bytes.NewBufferString(stringData))
    req.SetBasicAuth("root", "1")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error : %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("resp")
    fmt.Println(ToJson(resp))

    var b bytes.Buffer
    _, err = b.ReadFrom(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error : %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(b.String())
}

func ToJson(obj interface{}) string {
    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(&obj, "", "   ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error : %s", err)
    }
    strJson := string(b)

    return strJson
}
```

It gives output:

```
resp
{
   "Status": "500 Internal Server Error",
   "StatusCode": 500,
   "Proto": "HTTP/1.1",
   "ProtoMajor": 1,
   "ProtoMinor": 1,
   "Header": {
      "Cache-Control": [
         "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
      ],
      "Connection": [
         "Keep-Alive"
      ],
      "Content-Length": [
         "55"
      ],
      "Content-Type": [
         "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
      ],
      "Date": [
         "Mon Jun 08 10:47:46 MSK 2015"
      ],
      "Pragma": [
         "no-cache"
      ],
      "Server": [
         "OrientDB Server v.2.0.10 (build UNKNOWN@r; 2015-05-25 16:48:43+0000)"
      ]
   },
   "Body": {},
   "ContentLength": 55,
   "TransferEncoding": null,
   "Close": false,
   "Trailer": null,
   "Request": {
      "Method": "POST",
      "URL": {
         "Scheme": "http",
         "Opaque": "",
         "User": null,
         "Host": "localhost:2480",
         "Path": "/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql",
         "RawQuery": "",
         "Fragment": ""
      },
      "Proto": "HTTP/1.1",
      "ProtoMajor": 1,
      "ProtoMinor": 1,
      "Header": {
         "Authorization": [
            "Basic cm9vdDox"
         ]
      },
      "Body": {
         "Reader": {}
      },
      "ContentLength": 46,
      "TransferEncoding": null,
      "Close": false,
      "Host": "localhost:2480",
      "Form": null,
      "PostForm": null,
      "MultipartForm": null,
      "Trailer": null,
      "RemoteAddr": "",
      "RequestURI": "",
      "TLS": null
   },
   "TLS": null
}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text cannot be null
```

How to make this POST request work successfully, using GoLang, as I can do with POSTMAN chrome extension?

## Update

I made the same POST request successfully, using curl.

```
curl -X POST -u root:1 -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-urlencode "INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19"  http://localhost:2480/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql
```

It outputs:

```
{"result":[{"@type":"d","@rid":"#9:822","@version":1,"@class":"V","name":null}]}
```

## Update 2

Of course, I should not use `--data-urlencode` for `curl` command. 
The valid curl command is

```
curl -X POST -u root:1 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19"  http://localhost:2480/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql
{"result":[{"@type":"d","@rid":"#9:848","@version":1,"@class":"V","name":"jack","boss":"#11:19","@fieldTypes":"boss=x"}]}
```

I still have no clue how to make the similar GoLang POST request.

## Update 3

`url.QueryEscape` did not help me.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    // Why this stringData is lost and do not pass thgouht POST request?
    stringData := `INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19`
    stringData = url.QueryEscape(stringData)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:2480/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql", bytes.NewBufferString(stringData))
    req.SetBasicAuth("root", "1")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "Content-Type: text/plain")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error : %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("resp")
    fmt.Println(ToJson(resp))

    var b bytes.Buffer
    _, err = b.ReadFrom(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error : %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(b.String())
}

func ToJson(obj interface{}) string {
    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(&obj, "", "   ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error : %s", err)
    }
    strJson := string(b)

    return strJson
}
```

The result is the same:

```
resp
{
   "Status": "500 Internal Server Error",
   "StatusCode": 500,
   "Proto": "HTTP/1.1",
   "ProtoMajor": 1,
   "ProtoMinor": 1,
   "Header": {
      "Cache-Control": [
         "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
      ],
      "Connection": [
         "Keep-Alive"
      ],
      "Content-Length": [
         "55"
      ],
      "Content-Type": [
         "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
      ],
      "Date": [
         "Mon Jun 08 19:39:12 MSK 2015"
      ],
      "Pragma": [
         "no-cache"
      ],
      "Server": [
         "OrientDB Server v.2.0.10 (build UNKNOWN@r; 2015-05-25 16:48:43+0000)"
      ]
   },
   "Body": {},
   "ContentLength": 55,
   "TransferEncoding": null,
   "Close": false,
   "Trailer": null,
   "Request": {
      "Method": "POST",
      "URL": {
         "Scheme": "http",
         "Opaque": "",
         "User": null,
         "Host": "localhost:2480",
         "Path": "/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql",
         "RawQuery": "",
         "Fragment": ""
      },
      "Proto": "HTTP/1.1",
      "ProtoMajor": 1,
      "ProtoMinor": 1,
      "Header": {
         "Authorization": [
            "Basic cm9vdDox"
         ],
         "Content-Type": [
            "Content-Type: text/plain"
         ]
      },
      "Body": {
         "Reader": {}
      },
      "ContentLength": 60,
      "TransferEncoding": null,
      "Close": false,
      "Host": "localhost:2480",
      "Form": null,
      "PostForm": null,
      "MultipartForm": null,
      "Trailer": null,
      "RemoteAddr": "",
      "RequestURI": "",
      "TLS": null
   },
   "TLS": null
}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text cannot be null
```

Also, I changed content-type to `text/plain` in `curl` command.

```
curl -X POST -u root:1 -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19"  http://localhost:2480/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql
{"result":[{"@type":"d","@rid":"#9:858","@version":1,"@class":"V","name":"jack","boss":"#11:19","@fieldTypes":"boss=x"}]}
```

The result is the same, it's ok with `curl`, but not ok with `golang` POST.

## Update 4

What am I trying to do? I am implementing [OrientDB REST-interface](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/OrientDB-REST.html#post---command) for executing queries from a `GO` application.

Comment: Just curious: Does `bytes.Buffer` as created by `bytes.NewBufferString` implement `io.Reader`?

Comment: First: What makes you think that the request body as sent by Go is empty? It is not. Second: Your Java server states clearly that is requires a non null 'text', maybe you should provide one. Third: Use curl, not postman. postman is nice but curl makes clear what actually goes on.

Comment: @Volker here is the same working `curl` request: `curl -X POST -u root:1 -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-urlencode "INSERT INTO V SET name = 'jack', boss = #11:19"  http://localhost:2480/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql `

Comment: You realise the `Content-Type` header is the type of data that you are sending, `Accept` is the header to say what type of data you want sent back.

Comment: @Volker My Java server states about a non null 'text' because it receives empty data. I think so since I can get the same `text cannot be null` response, using `curl` by removing data: `curl -X POST -u root:1 -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-urlencode "" http://localhost:2480/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql`. It outputs
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text cannot be null`

Comment: Why do you send this SQL statement in URL-encoded form with curl but as a plain string with Go? And @thecoshman made a very valid point: Why do you set our Content-type to JSON but you send URL-encoded data? You might want to take a deeper look at how HTTP works and study the documentation of your API-endpoint of your Java server before trying to do it in Go. Trial and error programming is not helpful.

Comment: Just URL-encode your body as curl does it for you automatically (See https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryEscape). Note that your curl call is still wrong: Your content type is not JSON. One more: Instead of posting curl or postman examples you could post (or link) to your API endpoint specification/description.

Comment: As side note: I don't know know exactly what you are trying to do here, but sending raw sql statements as a post body makes my eyes squirt and my fingers twitch. I can only hope you are not actually doing this (even in an internal network) because security wise this is very, very bad. Just send a json/xml/postparam blob with data and parse and *validate* that serverside and only then create a sql statement out of this. Like this it is only a matter of time before you wonder who made all those new tables and who user 'Joe' is in your user table.

Comment: @Volker I tried to use `QueryEscape` and changed content type to `text/plain` for `curl`,  but the result is the same (Update3 above)

Comment: @RickA While plaintext SQL statements in the body is definitely strange it seems to be that way in OrientDB; at least they support SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation clearly helps. From the OrientDB documentation documentation [1]:

> All the requests must have these 2 headers:
>
> ```
> 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate'
> 'Content-Length': <content-length>
> ```
>
> Where the  is the length of the request's body.

And you do not set the Accept-Encoding header. Most probably this is all you need (and not escaping the body).

[1] http://orientdb.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/OrientDB-REST.html#headers